# VBScript Regular Expresssions - Match with multiple

Tags: regex, vbscript

Is it possible to match based on something similar to && conditions? On the following URL, I see how we can use the | annotation for an Or, where it will match if either are true but what about if multiple are true?

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/44/vbscript-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet

For instance, lets say I have the following strings

"SuperItem_BoxA"
"Super_ItemBoxB"

and I want a regular expression to return Super_ItemBoxB using logic like

if string contains 'Item' && 'Super' && 'BoxB'

If I were to do "Super|Item|BoxB" it will return both of these since they are or conditions.

Comment: Don't you want to extract words? Why use regex if you just can check for 3 substrings in a string with `InStr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(?i)super.*?item.*?boxb
```

Comment: Please do not add superfluous text to work around the minimum answer length. If your answer is too short, try adding a description of your code instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
\b(?=\w*Super)(?=\w*Item)(?=\w*BoxB)\w+
```

[image]
**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\w*Super)` - the word must contain `Super`
- `(?=\w*Item)` - the word must contain `Item`
- `(?=\w*BoxB)` - the word must contain `BoxB`
- `\w+` - consume 1+ word chars.